# What am I missing here? Looping with dialog boxes

Tags: java

I am not sure why this code is not working.

I am suppose to have another dialog box appear after the user selects yes or no, but whenever I run the program, it asks for y or no and then nothing happens after.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String number;
    boolean yn = true;

    do {
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number");

        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);

        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }

        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
        System.out.println(min + " " + max);

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another number? (y/n)");
        String ny = in.nextLine();

        if (ny.equals("n")) {
            yn = false;
        }

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ny);


    } while (yn == true);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The max number is " + max + " and the mininum number is " + min);

}
```

}

Comment: It's waiting on input from the scanner. I'm guessing that's not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

The program stops on

```
String ny = in.nextLine();
```

waiting for input from System.in based on the Scanner defined on the first line.

If you enter 'n' on the console and press enter then the program carries on and shows the next dialog box.

I guess you meant to say:

```
String ny = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another number? (y/n)");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that you are not accepting the input from the panel, and are instead taking it from the console. To solve this, set ny to be equal to the input from the JPane, like so:

```
String ny = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another number? (y/n)");
```

However, there is another issue, which is this line:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ny);
```

It creates a pane that you don't need that displays y or n, and doesn't accept input. This line doesn't need to be there, so you should remove it. Your code works fine otherwise.